# Fix for workstation-domain "trust" issues after Anniversary Update?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

We have several hundred PCs running Windows 10 Pro. After receiving the "Anniversary Update" some of them are experiencing the following errors on domain user login attempts:

1. The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.
   or;
2. The security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship.

I can fix the problem by unjoining and rejoining the domain, or sometimes renaming the PC is required. But with hundreds of PCs, it is getting time consuming.

Does anyone by chance know how to prevent this issue from occurring? Does this issue indicate something on our domain is configured wrong?

Thanks!

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: I discovered that the PC account on the DC was removed after the Anniversary update was installed and the PC was rebooted. It was there before the update. This PC has been operating properly as a domain workstation for a year before the update.

A BIT MORE INFO: I should have mentioned this in the original post: these PCs are all cloned PCs. They were all cloned from one PC, joined domain and renamed, then registered using a valid license key. They have been working fine for over a year...until this update. Maybe something left over from the cloning process causes the issue? I am not sure.

Comment: Have you checked the event logs.  Anything that happened in particular that stands out?

Comment: This stands out -- "The session setup to the Windows Domain Controller \\DC1.<DOMAINNAME>.com for the domain <DOMAINNAME> failed because the Domain Controller did not have an account CPC-169$ needed to set up the session by this computer CPC-169." So I confirmed on the DC and the PC account is not there. But it was before the Anniversary Update. This PC has been operating properly as a domain workstation for a year using the same name. For some reason it has been removed. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Useful trick : unplug the machine from the network and reboot.  Attempt to log in using the old user name and password.

After you log in, replug the network.  The network may or may not work after logging in, and the computer may or may not be able to connect to the domain after logging in.  It sounds like you have a lot of computers down, so give it a try.  If it works normally on network functions, then reboot and try to login normally.  If it logs in normally, tell everyone to temporarily unplug, log in, replug, and reboot.

This has worked for me in the past when the nameservers weren't working properly , and allowed work to be done on the machine.

Comment: +1 for a very good temporary fix Christopher! As stated in my original question, I would really like to know "Does anyone by chance know how to prevent this issue from occurring? Does this issue indicate something on our domain is configured wrong?". Since a Google search seems to indicate no one else is having this issue with the Anniversary update (or no one has posted anything to that effect yet), it indicates to me that something is wrong with our domain configuration, or with these cloned PCs that are experiencing this issue. I am hoping someone can help me determine what that is...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a preventative answer...  The Anniversary Update probably handles domain authentication differently than earlier versions.  Perhaps the domain controllers have an update that hasn't applied yet.  MS knows that many business run on imaged machines, so this sort of thing should be in their standard test cases.

Comment: Thanks again Christopher! I believe our DCs are running the latest updates. Until we have more information we plan to block the Anniversary Update on the rest of our PCs that have not installed it yet (which is most of them)...we run WSUS that provides all updates and we will just leave this update unapproved. The few PCs that did install it were mistakenly not using our WSUS at the time.